# Very basic groovy programming questions about passing parameters, etc

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, macros

So Groovy based macros in Intellij IDEA are my excuse for learning Groovy.

Groovy Version: 2.4.9 JVM: 1.8.0_144 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10

See `groovyScript("groovy code")` here in the IntelliJ docs:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-template-variables.html

I have a script that IntelliJ calls and it binds the parameters as _1, _2..._n and also there is an _editor... parameter? IDK if it's a parameter or not. There has to be some means for getting the transformed input back out though.

Here is my test script:

```
public class IvyPaister {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println _1
        println _editor
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
startup failed:
    C:\path\to\script.groovy: 4: Apparent variable
    '_1' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.
    Possible causes:
    You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static
    context.
    You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
    You attempted to use a method '_1' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
    @ line 4, column 41.
    yPaister app = new IvyPaister(_1, _edito
    ^

    C:\path\to\script\pasteIvyDependenciesAsMaven.groovy: 4: Apparent variable
    '_editor' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or
    class. Possible causes:
    You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static
    context.
    You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
    You attempted to use a method '_editor' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the
    grammar.
    @ line 4, column 45.
    ster app = new IvyPaister(_1, _editor);
    ^
```

This makes sense but I don't know what to do about it in this language. Have tried some variations but no dice.  Clues? Ideas? A bone?

Comment: Been there. Done that. Couldn't even have gotten this far without it. Problem is not much beyond that seems available.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to:

```
println _1
println _editor
```

Comment: No such property: _1 for class: pasteIvyDependenciesAsMaven

Comment: That you know of, are there any versions of Groovy that need to be handled differently?

Comment: Not that I can think of...  Not sure what the implication is though ;-)

Comment: What's your second argument to "groovyScript"? _1 is available only if there are more arguments. Just tried with a variable whose expression value is "groovyScript("/home/peter/work/script.groovy", "2")" and it works for me.

Comment: BTW you don't need to put code into external file; you can write it inline in the first argument of "groovyScript"

Comment: "println" will just print values to the IDE console which you probably won't even see. You need to return an actual value from the script, which would be the value of the last expression inside of it